# Background Color Change Switch Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a dark/light theme. When I click to flip into light, the function runs. but `darken();` seems to be ignored. Am I missing something? no error messages.

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
<span class="slider round" onclick="contrast();"></span>
```

```
var m = 1

function lightup() {
    document.getElementById('header-wrap').style.backgroundColor = "white"
}

function darken() {
    document.getElementById('header-wrap').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
}

function contrast() {
    if (m = 1) {
        m = 2
        lightup();
    }
    else if (m = 2) {
        m = 1
        darken();
    }
}
```

`contrast();` and `lightup();` both fire as intended. `darken();` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value comparison should be done using `m === 1` or `m == 1`. `m = 1` is assignment operator

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var m = 1

function lightup() {
    document.getElementById('header-wrap').style.backgroundColor = "white"
}

function darken() {
    document.getElementById('header-wrap').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
}

function contrast() {
    if (m === 1) {
        m = 2
        lightup();
    }
    else if (m === 2) {
        m = 1
        darken();
    }
}
```

```css
#header-wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrap"></div>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round" onclick="contrast();">Change</span>
</label>
```

A better apprach is to make the function trigger on the change event of checkbox. Check the `checked` status of the checkbox and toggle the background color.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
const element = document.getElementById('header-wrap');

function contrast() {
    element.style.backgroundColor = checkbox.checked ? "white" : 'black';
}
```

```css
#header-wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrap"></div>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="contrast();">
    <span class="slider round">Change</span>
</label>
```

Comment: cant believe I missed that.